# How to convert tsvector?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, tsvector

A typical and relevant application of [tsvectot](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-controls.html) is to query and summarize information about the set of occurred words and about its frequency... And JSONB is the natural choice (!) to represent `tsvectot` datatype for these "querying applications"... So,

There are a simple workaround to cast *tsvector* into *JSONB*?

Example: counting global frequency of words of a cached tsvectot's, will be something like this query

```
 SELECT r.key as word, SUM(r.value) as occurrences
 FROM (
     SELECT jsonb_each(kx_tsvectot::jsonb) as r FROM terms
 ) t
 GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[`ts_stat()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-features.html)** function, which will give you exactly what you need

> **word** text — the value of a lexeme
>   **ndoc** integer — number of documents (tsvectors) the word occurred in
>   **nentry** integer — total number of occurrences of the word

Example may be the following:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  tsv TSVECTOR
);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
  ('word'::TSVECTOR),
  ('second word'::TSVECTOR),
  ('third word'::TSVECTOR);

SELECT * FROM
  ts_stat('SELECT tsv FROM t');
```

Result:

```
  word  | ndoc | nentry 
--------+------+--------
 word   |    3 |      3
 third  |    1 |      1
 second |    1 |      1
(3 rows)
```

If you still want to convert it to *jsonb* you can use cast `word` from *text* to *jsonb*.

Comment: thanks to the help!  [My link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html) did not mention  [ts_stats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-features.html), so **+1** by mention, and expose the use in a didactic form for  readers (!)... It is not the accepted answer, only because it is not "my dream" :-)  The dream is a simple and fast casting to internal binary representations, that are very very similar, so need a fast casting.  Let's see if another one shows some more clues to the question.

Comment: well, in this case you need to do the following ((tsvector_val)::TEXT) 1st, but than trick will be to use `regexp_split_to_array()` in order to get all lexemes from `TEXT` and than perform cast to `JSONB` and aggregate with count() @PeterKrauss

Comment: Yes, it works, but regex convertions are so so more CPU-consuming than a simple internal conversion, that I was explained... The binary information is there, and there are no rational to not use it.